# convert html to word not working as example

Tags: html, asp.net

I am trying to convert html to word. I have found so many codes over the net but none of them works. They are worked with string builder or some with others. I have given a code. In debugger it goes through all the codes without error but no file is getting downloaded.

```
public void converToWord(string htmlContent,string name)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
    string strFileName = name + ".doc";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + strFileName);

    StringBuilder strHTMLContent = new StringBuilder();
    strHTMLContent.Append("<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"><head></head><body>");
    strHTMLContent.Append(htmlContent);
    strHTMLContent.Append("</body></html>");

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTMLContent);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();  
}
```

i got an error it says {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}

Comment: it says {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

while the button is in update panel and it does not work properly.everything seems fine but it does not get downloaded.it is a very common problem that happens.just put o a trigger to the button that is firing the event and it will start to work just very much fine.